# Lowering powers of $\cos^2x \sin^4x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

First, I will be straight up, this is a homework question.

I need to write $\cos^2 x \sin^4 x$ in terms of cosine to the first power. I know that $\sin^4x$ =

$$ \frac{3-4\cos 2x+\cos 4x}{8}$$

from there I go:

$$ \frac{1+\cos 2x}{2} \cdot \frac{3-4\cos 2x+\cos 4x}{8}$$

$$ \frac{3(1 + \cos 2x) - 4\cos 2x(1 + \cos 2x) + \cos 4x (1 + \cos 2x)} {16} $$

$$ \frac{3 + 3\cos 2x - 4\cos 2x \color{red}{+} 4 \cos^2 2x + \cos 4x + \cos 4x \cos 2x}{16}$$

$$ \frac{3 - \cos 2x + \cos 4x + 4 \frac{1 + \cos 4x}{2} \cos 4x  \cos 2x}{16}$$

Then $$ 4 \frac{1 + \cos 4x}{2}$$ simplifies to $$ 2 + 2\cos 4x$$

adding this into the rest of the fraction gives me

$$ \frac{5 - \cos 2x + 3\cos 4x + \cos 4x \cos 2x}{16}$$

However, the answer sheet that I have says the answer is

$$ \frac{1 - \cos 2x - \cos 4x + \cos 2x \cos 4x }{16}$$

This is problem $13$ from section $7.3$ of [Stewart, Redlin and Watson precalculus $6$th edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0840068077)

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The red sign is wrong.

Comment: Did someone edit this sign red to show you? That's a pretty creative way to answer the question.

Comment: Oh my gosh, of course it's a tiny mistake like that. Thankyou @Mariog! If that was an answer I would accept it, but since it's just a comment take my +1.

Answer (score 1):

There is a systematic approach to solve such questions, based on complex numbers.

We have $\cos kx=\dfrac{e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}}2=\dfrac{z^k+z^{-k}}2$ and $\sin kx=\dfrac{e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}}{2i}=\dfrac{z^k-z^{-k}}{2i}$, where $z=e^{ix}$.

The expression can be rewritten
$$\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}\right)^4=\frac{z^6+z^{-6}-2z^4-2z^{-4}-z^2-z^{-2}+4}{64}=\frac{\cos6x-2\cos4x-\cos2x+2}{32}.$$

Comment: This differs from the official answer, as it lowers the powers to a minimum, even avoiding products.

Comment: I may be wrong about this, but I believe you want to change the last 4 to a 2.

Comment: @user84413: you are quite right, thanks a lot. When simplifying the $64$ to $32$, I forgot to adjust the $4$.

Comment: Another approach may be $$\cos^2 x\sin^4 x = (\cos x\sin x)^2\sin^2x=\dots$$

Comment: @JohnJoy: this is not helpful in the systematic approach, is it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found:

$$cos^2(x)sin^4(x)=\frac{1}{32}(-cos(2x)-2cos(4x)+cos(6x)+x)$$

Verify the indenty:

$$32cos(x)^2sin(x)^4=2-cos(2x)-2cos(4x)+cos(6x)$$
$$6-2cos(2x)-4-4cos(4x)+2cos(4x)+cos(2x)+cos(6x)=2-cos(2x)-2cos(4x)+cos(6x)$$
$$\frac{1}{32}(-cos(2x)-2cos(4x)+cos(6x)+x)=\frac{1}{32}(-cos(2x)-2cos(4x)+cos(6x)+x)$$

The left hand side and right hand side are equal!

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered, but I needed a more traditional approach to the problem for school.  Finally figured it out.

The following solution leads to the final answer of:
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = \frac{\cos(6x)-2\cos(4x)-\cos(2x)+2}{32}
$$

$$
cos^2x = \left(\frac{1+cos(2x)}{2}\right)
$$
$$
sin^4x = \left(\frac{3-4cos(2x)+cos(4x)}{8}\right)
$$
Proof of sin<sup>4</sup>(x) identity is at the end in case anyone needs it

$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\left(\frac{1+cos(2x)}{2}\right)
\left(\frac{3-4cos(2x)+cos(4x)}{8}\right)
$$
multiply
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{3-4cos(2x)+cos(4x)+3cos(2x)-4cos^2(2x)+cos(2x)cos(4x)}{16}
$$
combine like terms
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{3-cos(2x)+cos(4x)-4cos^2(2x)+cos(2x)cos(4x)}{16}
$$
reduce the cos<sup>2</sup>(2x)
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{3-cos(2x)+cos(4x)-4\left(\frac{1+cos(4x)}{2}\right)+cos(2x)cos(4x)}{16}
$$
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{3-cos(2x)+cos(4x)-2\left(1+cos(4x)\right)+cos(2x)cos(4x)}{16}
$$
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{3-cos(2x)+cos(4x)-2-2cos(4x)+cos(2x)cos(4x)}{16}
$$
combine like terms
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{1-cos(2x)-cos(4x)+cos(2x)cos(4x)}{16}
$$

On the tests I'm taking, you can't leave cos(2x)cos(4x) like that, so we have to get rid of that.
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{1-cos(2x)-cos(4x)+cos(2x)(cos(2x+2x))}{16}
$$
We know the formula for cos(x+y)=cos(x)cos(y)-sin(x)sin(y), so let's plug 2x into that formula for both x and y.
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{1-cos(2x)-cos(4x)+cos(2x)(cos(2x)cos(2x)-sin(2x)sin(2x))}{16}
$$
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{1-cos(2x)-cos(4x)+cos(2x)(cos^2(2x)-sin^2(2x))}{16}
$$
I don't like that sine, so I'm going to use the Pythagorean identity to convert it to cosine.
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{1-cos(2x)-cos(4x)+cos(2x)(cos^2(2x)-(1-cos^2(2x)))}{16}
$$
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{1-cos(2x)-cos(4x)+cos(2x)(cos^2(2x)-1+cos^2(2x))}{16}
$$
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{1-cos(2x)-cos(4x)+cos(2x)(2cos^2(2x)-1)}{16}
$$
That cos(2x) has just been sitting out there in front.  It's time to multiply it.
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{1-cos(2x)-cos(4x)+2cos^3(2x)-cos(2x)}{16}
$$
Combine like terms again.
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{1-2cos(2x)-cos(4x)+2cos^3(2x)}{16}
$$
We use the identity for cos(3x) to find cos<sup>3</sup>(x).  At the same time, we substitute x (in the identity formula) for 2x (in our equation). The proof for cos<sup>3</sup>(x) will be shown at the end for those that want to see it.

$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{1-2cos(2x)-cos(4x)+2\left(\frac{cos(6x)+3cos(2x)}{4}\right)}{16}
$$
2 divided by 4 is 1/2
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{1-2cos(2x)-cos(4x)+\left(\frac{cos(6x)+3cos(2x)}{2}\right)}{16}
$$
Get rid of that annoying fraction in the numerator by multiplying everything by 2.
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{2-4cos(2x)-2cos(4x)+cos(6x)+3cos(2x)}{32}
$$
Combine like terms.
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{2-cos(2x)-2cos(4x)+cos(6x)}{32}
$$
Rearrange some stuff in the numerator, and the answer matches.
$$
cos^2(x)sin^4(x) = 
\frac{\cos(6x)-2\cos(4x)-\cos(2x)+2}{32}
$$

**Proofs**
Now to the proofs I promised earlier.
$$
\mathbb{First Proof}
$$
$$
sin^4x = \left(\frac{3-4cos(2x)+cos(4x)}{8}\right)
$$

$$
sin^4x = sin^2xsin^2x
$$
$$
sin^4x = 
\left(\frac{1-cos(2x)}{2}\right)
\left(\frac{1-cos(2x)}{2}\right)
$$
Multiply.
$$
sin^4x = \left(\frac{1-cos(2x)-cos(2x)+cos^2(2x)}{4}\right)
$$
Combine like terms.
$$
sin^4x = \left(\frac{1-2cos(2x)+cos^2(2x)}{4}\right)
$$
Reduce that cos<sup>2</sup>(2x)
$$
sin^4x = \left(\frac{1-2cos(2x)+\left(\frac{1+cos(4x)}{2}\right)}{4}\right)
$$
Get rid of that ugly fraction in the numerator by multiplying by 2.
$$
sin^4x = \left(\frac{2-4cos(2x)+1+cos(4x)}{8}\right)
$$
Combine like terms.
$$
sin^4x = \left(\frac{3-4cos(2x)+cos(4x)}{8}\right)
$$
The end.

$$
\mathbb{Second Proof}
$$
$$
cos^3(2x) = \left(\frac{cos(6x)+3cos(2x)}{4}\right)
$$
If this is new for you, it might seem a bit roundabout, but bear with me.  First I need to prove that
$$
cos(3x) = 4cos^3(x)-3cos(x)
$$
Maybe you can already see where this leads.  We'll use that equation to work out the equation above it.
To help clarify things down the line, I'm going to use "a" rather than "x" for the proof.
$$
cos(3a) = cos(2a + a)
$$
We know the identity for cos(x + y)=cos(x)cos(y)-sin(x)sin(y), so let's say that x=2a and y=a.
$$
cos(3a) = cos(2a)cos(a)-sin(2a)sin(a)
$$
Let's get rid of all of those pesky 2a's using the double angle identity: 
[cos(2x)=cos<sup>2</sup>(x)-sin<sup>2</sup>(x)
sin(2x)=2sin(x)cos(x)]

$$
cos(3a) = (cos^2(a)-sin^2(a))cos(a)-(2sin(a)cos(a))sin(a)
$$
Multiply through
$$
cos(3a) = cos^3(a)-sin^2(a)cos(a)-2sin^2(a)cos(a)
$$
We want everything to be in terms of cosine, so let's switch the sines to cosines using the Pythagorean identity.
$$
cos(3a) = cos^3(a)-(1-cos^2(a))cos(a)-2(1-cos^2(a))cos(a)
$$
Multiply through again.
$$
cos(3a) = cos^3(a)-(cos(a)-cos^3(a))-(2cos(a)-2cos^3(a))
$$
Carry the signs through (not to be confused with sines).
$$
cos(3a) = cos^3(a)-cos(a)+cos^3(a))-2cos(a)+2cos^3(a)
$$
Combine like terms
$$
cos(3a) = 4cos^3(a)-3cos(a)
$$
Now that we found out what cos(3a) is, we can rearrange the equation to solve for cos<sup>3</sup>(a).

Let's start by switching the sides.
$$
4cos^3(a)-3cos(a) = cos(3a)
$$
$$
4cos^3(a) = cos(3a) + 3cos(a)
$$
$$
cos^3(a) = \left(\frac{cos(3a)+3cos(a)}{4}\right)
$$

Okay, now we've solved for cos<sup>3</sup>(a), but we're not quite done yet.  Remember that the original equation asked what cos<sup>3</sup>(2x) was.  To find that, we substitute 2x for a.
$$
a = 2x
$$
$$
cos^3(2x) = \left(\frac{cos(3*2x)+3cos(2x)}{4}\right)
$$
$$
cos^3(2x) = \left(\frac{cos(6x)+3cos(2x)}{4}\right)
$$
The end.